# WebScraping With BS4, AttributeError with Find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the code im running.

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SAS.ST/?guccounter=1')
soup=bs4,BeautifulSoup(r.text,"xml")

soup.find_all('div')
```

And when i run it the output is

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/darre/Desktop/script.py3", line 8, in <module>
> bi=soup.find_all('div') AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: This seems really basic, what do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging whatsoever? Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is error, use `soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")` instead of

```
soup=bs4,BeautifulSoup(r.text,"xml")
```

BeautifulSoup use different parser details here [parser description here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! 
But now when i run the code nothing shows up. I want it to show all the DIV elements. 

following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rONhdonaWUo

Comment: You did not mention which div element want to extract, then i write down some code for you so that its help you to understand . thanks.  for data in soup.find_all('table', class_='W(100%)'):
    for item in  data.find_all("span"):
        print(item.text , sep=' ') , its collect some data from table.